# If statement in Node red (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm trying to evaluate a value in node red :
[image]

from the join node I'm getting the following:

[image]

so what I'm trying to do in the function is to check the  1. sent value:

```
var payload  = msg.payload; 
if (msg.payload[0] === "0" ){
    msg.payload  =0;
} else {
    msg.payload = 1;
}

//msg.payload = payload[0];
return msg;
```

So my question why am I getting the if statement is false ?

thanks for any hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to check but checking the value of the payload property can be done as follows:

```
if(typeof msg.payload === "object"){
    if(msg.payload[0].value === 0) { // Use "0" if this value is a string, but I guess not by inspecting your data.
        // Your code
    } else {
        // Other code
    }
}
else {
    // msg.payload is not an array
}
```

According to your data, you have two situations, either `msg.payload` is an array or either it is a value.

Comment: Allow me to add one explanation here for some who don't know. msg.payload is actually an array but with "typeof" it will return "object". Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof